# Formatting couchdb-lucene results with a couchdb list

Tags: lucene, couchdb, couchapp, couchdb-lucene

Situation...

I have a simple couchapp that lists out emails that are stored in the couch database, these emails are queried with a simple view and then piped through a list to give me a pretty table that I can click on the emails to view them. That works great.

The next evolution of this app was to add some fulltext searching of the subject line of the emails with couchdb-lucene, and I think I have that nailed down as well as I *can* search using lucene and get valid results back.  What I can't quite grasp is how do I take those results and pipe them back into my existing list function so they get formated correctly?

Here is an example of my view + list URL that gives me the HTML
`http://localhost:5984/tenant103/_design/Email/_list/emaillist/by_type?startkey=["Email",2367264774866]&endkey=["Email",0]&limit=20&descending=true&include_docs=true`

And here is my search URL that also gives me results
`http://localhost:5984/_fti/local/tenant103/_design/Email/by_subject?q=OM-2875&include_docs=true`

My thinking was I would build the URL like this
`http://localhost:5984/_fti/local/tenant103/_design/Email/_list/emaillist/by_subject?q=OM-2875&include_docs=true`

But that just returns

```
{
reason: "bad_request",
code: 400
}
```

This is a learning project for myself with CouchDB so I may not be getting some simple concepts here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CouchDB-Lucene does not natively support list transformations and CouchDB can only apply list transformations to its own map/reduce views. Sorry about that!

Robert Newson.

Comment: Well, that makes sense why I couldn't figure it out!  Thanks for the info, I'll refactor the list work to be client side for now so I can still share the code.